# Cannot Display Text input in a newText Box

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Currently I'm trying to make a program that allows me to input text inside different textboxes. From there, I have a button to display the text in a textbox below. The issue I'm running into is when I click the button, nothing is displayed in that output textbox.

For this simple program, I'm using C and the Windows API to do this.

Declaring the variables for textboxes

```
#define GENERATE_BUTTON 1
HMENU hMenu;
HWND hFirst,hLast;
```

The Generate Button Case used for the button

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch ( msg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(wp)
        {

        case 1:
            MessageBeep(MB_OK);
            break;

        case GENERATE_BUTTON:
            char Fname[30],Lname[30],out[200];
            GetWindowText(hFirst,Fname,30);
            GetWindowText(hLast,Lname,30);

            strcpy(out,Fname);
            strcat(out,Lname);

            SetWindowText(hOut,out);

            break;

        }
```

The textbox code

```
void AddControls(HWND hWnd)
{
    CreateWindowW(L"static",L"First Name:",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,10,10,100,20,hWnd,
                  NULL,NULL,NULL);
    hFirst = CreateWindowW(L"Edit",L"",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD , 90,10,130,20,hWnd,
                  NULL,NULL,NULL);

    CreateWindowW(L"static",L"Last Name:",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,10,40,100,20,hWnd,
                  NULL,NULL,NULL);
    hLast = CreateWindowW(L"Edit",L"",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD , 90,40,130,20,hWnd,
                  NULL,NULL,NULL);

    hOut = CreateWindowW(L"Edit","",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER, 25,300,500,150,hWnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);

    CreateWindowW(L"Button",L"Display",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,250,410,70,20,hWnd,{HMENU}GENERATE_BUTTON,NULL,NULL);
```

I'm just wanting it to display the first name and last name, but as of now when I click the display button it does nothing.

Comment: Your `WindowProcedure()` should be generating a compiler error, as your `switch` has multiple `case` statements with the same numeric value of 1. Get rid of `case 1` and move the `MessageBeep()` inside of `case GENERATE_BUTTON`.

Comment: Also this code has some another flaws: 1. Mixing ANSI/Unicode, 2. strcpy(out, Fname) and strcpy(out, Lname) dont produce what you want

Answer (score 0):

I've run your code over again. There are some mistakes that need to be corrected.

```
CreateWindowW(L"Button",L"Display",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,250,500,70,20,hWnd,(HMENU)GENERATE_BUTTON,NULL,NULL);
```

Button controls cannot be placed in edit controls, otherwise they will be invalid.

I didn't see your `hOut` statement. Maybe you need to pay attention to it.

As @Remy Lebeau said, Delete `case 1` .

Here's the code I've modified to get the results you need.

```
case GENERATE_BUTTON:
{
   TCHAR Fname[512], Lname[512], out[512];
   GetWindowText(hFirst, Fname, 512);
   GetWindowText(hLast, Lname, 512);
   wcscpy_s(out, 512, Fname);
   wcscat_s(out, 512, Lname);
   SetWindowText(hOut, out);

   MessageBeep(MB_OK);
   break;
}
```

Comment: "*Button controls cannot be placed in edit controls*" - the OP's code is not trying to do that. The Edit control and the Button are being created as children of the same parent, not the Button as a child of the Edit control.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I know, when I tried to reproduce it with his code, I found that his button control was in the edit control, mainly the coordinate problem, so I reminded him to pay attention to this point.